# url rewrite in htaccess file goes to 404 Page Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Following is my full .htaccess file. it works fine in local host. But it goes to 404 page not found in shared hosting. can anybody help me to solve this issue

```
RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteBase /


    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?search_location=([^\s&]+)&search_for=([^\s&]+)&search_type=([^\s&]+)&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4? [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$index.php?search_location=$1&search_for=$2&search_type=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't be one line like that:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$index.php?search_location=$1&search_for=$2&search_type=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?search_location=$1&search_for=$2&search_type=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```

With one space after `?$`